# Docker: NGINX container not routing static assets to Wordpress container correctly

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have a VPS with a main NGINX container and different services running inside Docker containers. I have a subdomain configuration for every service, and that works fine.

Now I tried to add a Wordpress container to the infrastructure and it works, except for the static assets, which keep returning a `403 Forbidden` error.

This is my Wordpress `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  blog-wp:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6
    container_name: blog-wp
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
    depends_on:
      - blog-db
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=${DB_PORT}
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=${DB_DATABASE}
```

Nothing special about that.

This is my NGINX config file, inside the Docker container:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    server_name blog.domain.com;

    return 301 https://blog.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name blog.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         allow all;
         root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @apache;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        allow all;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ ^/.user.ini {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  .(svg|svgz)$ {
        types {}
        default_type image/svg+xml;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location @apache {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://blog-wp:8080;
    }

    location ~[^?]*/$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://blog-wp:8080;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://blog-wp:8080;
    }

    location ~/. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

And this is what I get on the browser:

[image]

The Wordpress container responds correctly, but static assets are misconfigured.

Any suggestion?
Thanx.

Comment: Have you verified the user that nginx is running as has access to the static files that it is trying to serve?

Comment: As mentioned by @ConspicuousCompiler check the permissions but bear in mind that given your

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        allow all;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
```
and `root /var/www/html;`
the file `wp-includes/blocks/navigation/stule.min.css` needs to be accessible from `/var/www/html/wp-includes/blocks/navigation/stule.min.css`

It is not clear what your wordpress_data volume setting is ... so impossible to help without you sharing these details